# Python - Direct linking blocking via iFrames, can I still get the binaries?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a scraper script that pulls binary content off publishers websites. Its built to replace the manual action of saving hundreds of individual pdf files that colleagues would other wise have to undertake.

The websites are credential based, and we have the correct credentials and permissions to collect this content.

I have encountered a website that has the pdf file inside an iFrame.

I can extract the content URL from the HTML. When I feed the URL to the content grabber, I collect a small piece of HTML that says: `<html><body>Forbidden: Direct file requests are not allowed.</body></html>`

I can feed the URL directly to the browser, and the PDF file resolves correctly.

I am assuming that there is a session cookie (or something, I'm not 100% comfortable with the terminology) that gets sent with the request to show that the `GET` request comes from a live session, not a remote link.

I looked at the refering URL, and saw these different URLs that point to the same article that I collected over a day of testing (I have scrubbed identifers from the URL):-

http://content_provider.com/NDM3NTYyNi45MTcxODM%3D/elibrary//title/issue/article.pdf
http://content_provider.com/NDM3NjYyMS4wNjU3MzY%3D/elibrary//title/issue/article.pdf
http://content_provider.com/NDM3Njc3Mi4wOTY3MDM%3D/elibrary//title/issue/article.pdf 
http://content_provider.com/NDM3Njg3Ni4yOTc0NDg%3D/elibrary//title/issue/article.pdf

This suggests that there is something in the URL that is unique, and needs associating to something else to circumvent the direct link detector.

Any suggestions on how to get round this problem?

Answer (score 0):

OK. The answer was Cookies and headers. I collected the `get` header info via httpfox and made a identical header object in my script, and i grabbed the session ID from request.cookie and sent the cookie with each request.

For good measure I also set the user agent to a known working browser agent, just in case the server was checking agent details.

Works fine.